# Why is a normalized fundamental matrix non-singular for all t?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation

**Definition**: An $n\times n$ matrix $\Phi$ with the property that its columns are solutions of $\dot X = AX$, and linearly independent at $t_0$, is said to be a **fundamental matrix** of $\dot X = AX$ at $t_0$.

Suppose now that  $\Psi(t)$ is a fundamental matrix and thus $\Psi(t)\Psi^{−1} (t_0)$ is a **normalized fundamental matrix** at $t_0$, assuming that $\Psi^{−1} (t_0)$ exists.

But, why is it that $\Psi(t)\Psi^{−1} (t_0)$ is non-singular for every $t$?

I understand that at $t_0$, $\Psi(t_0)\Psi^{−1} (t_0) = {\rm Id}$ which is non-singular (and obviously from $\Psi^{−1} (t_0)$ existence) but why for all t?

Comment: It follows immediately from Liouville's formula for $\det \Psi(t)$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_formula).

Comment: @JohnB, thanks for your answer, does this also apply for if $A$ is a constant matrix? while the fundamental matrix is still time dependent.

Comment: I guess that it would work, just that the trace of $A$ will not be time dependent and we can take it out of the integral? having $det(\Phi (t)) = det(\Phi (t_0))e^{tr(A){\int^t_{t_0}}dt}$

Comment: Indeed, $\det e^{tA}=e^{t\,{\rm tr}A}$.

Comment: @JohnB thank you again

Comment: look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4458262/help-with-understanding-the-proof-for-fundamental-matrices-are-non-singular-fo